# Can I set ListView and ListFragment selected color in an application-wide theme?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-theme, android-listfragment

I have an application with two Activities. The first Activity is a ListActivity. The second Activity is a FragmentActivity, with two Fragments in it. The first Fragment is a ListFragment. I'd like to format the application using a custom Theme that extends Theme.Light. I've successfully changed the windowBackground, but when I try to change listSelector nothing happens. Is it possible to do this through a Theme, or do I have to do it separately on each list? Here's my code:

My Custom Theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <style name="StitchTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:listSelector">#ffffff</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then, in my Manifest, I put:

```
 <application
android:theme="@style/StitchTheme" >
```

I've also tried doing this by setting up a selector.xml and setting android:listSelector in my Theme, but it has no effect. Thoughts?

Comment: You may want to override the `listViewStyle` of the theme to point to a style which inherits from `Widget.ListView` and overrides the `android:listSelector` value.